# 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' In Stream.Read operation

Tags: c#, utf-8, stream, decode, encode

I am compressing a json using deflate compression technique and saving to sql server database. The json contains values from any culture ie. th-TH, zh-TW. The compressed string is getting saved successfully in database.

Json includes data like **{"@id":"2113","description":"อาหารเช้าคอนติเนนทัล"}**

Now when i read the same data from db, i convert it to bytes as 

`Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
encoding.GetBytes(data ?? string.Empty)`

The compression like this

```
public static string Compress(this string data, CompressionTypeOptions compressionType)
    {                           
            var bytes = Compress(Encoding.UTF-8.GetBytes(data ?? string.Empty), compressionType);
            return Encoding.UTF-8.GetString(bytes);
        }          
    }

private static byte[] Compress(byte[] data, CompressionTypeOptions compressionType)
    {            
        using (var memoryStream1 = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            using (var memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var compressionStream = CreateCompressionStream(compressionType, (Stream)memoryStream2,
                                                                    CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    CopyTo((Stream)memoryStream1, compressionStream);
                    compressionStream.Close();
                    return memoryStream2.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then decompressing like this

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            using (var compressionStream = CreateCompressionStream(compressionType, (Stream)memoryStream,
                                                                           CompressionMode.Decompress))
                return ReadAllBytesFromStream(compressionStream);
        }
```

Here is ReadAllBytesFromStream definition

```
private static byte[] ReadAllBytesFromStream(Stream stream)
    {

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var buffer1 = new byte[1];
            while (true)
            {
                int count = stream.Read(buffer1, 0, 1);
                if (count != 0)
                    memoryStream.Write(buffer1, 0, count);
                else
                    break;
            }
            var length = memoryStream.Length;
            var buffer2 = new byte[length];
            memoryStream.Position = 0L;
            memoryStream.Read(buffer2, 0, (int)length);
            return buffer2;
        }

    }
```

Getting error at `int count = stream.Read(buffer1, 0, 1);` as
'System.IO.InvalidDataException' 
'Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted.'

Any help is appreaciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a lot more information - what's the data type in the database? How are you writing the data? Is there any reason you're not just using `Stream.CopyTo` as a simpler alternative to the manual copying? Could you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem? You could probably simplify things a lot by taking the database out of the equation entirely: write to a file, then read from that file.

Comment: I gotta say... that `ReadAllBytesFromStream` looks ugly; suggestion: try `using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) { stream.CopyTo(memoryStream); return memoryStream.ToArray(); }` - if the error is in your buffer code, that should fix it

Comment: However! I suspect that either: `CreateCompressionStream` is creating the wrong type of decompression stream, or: the data is genuinely corrupt due to a storage error. Impossible to say without the data. As for "The compressed string is getting saved successfully in database." - until you can successfully read it out, you have no way of saying that. Note that we also can't see how `data` was read in the first place, or how it was stored - or the SQL data type, etc.